# Default position for a View for an Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I've created an eclipse plugin with a UI that I want to dock by default at the bottom in the Eclipse Java perspective (or any other perspective for that matter). How do I go about setting a default location for my plug-in UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...you can influence the initial size and position of your view in other perspectives by using the perspectiveExtensions extension point.

[More on this here.](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_set_the_size_or_position_of_my_view%3F)